# Lauching cypress test for the 2nd time, url lands on error page

Tags: cypress

I am trying to run a test using cypress, 1st time the test runs, it goes to the URL specified i.e. http://demo.nopcommerce.com/,
but 2nd time I run the test, the I am redirected to [https://demo.nopcommerce.com/page-not-found#/tests/integration\examples\Locators.spec.js](https://demo.nopcommerce.com/page-not-found#/tests/integration%5Cexamples%5CLocators.spec.js)

Here is my Script:

```
describe('Locating Elements', function() {
  it('Verify Types of locators', function() {
    cy.visit('http://demo.nopcommerce.com/')
    cy.get('#small-searchterms').type('Apple MacBook Pro 13-inch')
    cy.get('.button-1.search-box-button[value="Search"]').click()
    cy.get('.button-2.product-box-add-to-cart-button[value="Add to cart"]').click()
    cy.get('#product_enteredQuantity_4').clear().type('3')
    cy.get('input[type="button"][id="add-to-cart-button-4"]').click()
    cy.contains('The product has been added to your').should('be.visible')
    cy.get('.close').click()
    cy.contains('Shopping cart').click()
    cy.get('.estimate-shipping-button').click()
    cy.get('.estimate-shipping-popup').then(function() {
      cy.log('Hello.......')
      cy.get('#CountryId').select('India')
    })
  })
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try `https://demo.nopcommerce.com/` instead of `http://` inside cy.visit(), also please add `"chromeWebSecurity" : false` in cypress.json. When i tried with https://, it is working fine while rerunning the test.

May be a good idea to check with the dev team whether the `nopcommerce.com` domain/subdomain is configured properly to accepts `http://` requests.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the same solution as suggested.